# If wire was thread

Tags: wire, materials, conductors

I have a small paper lantern that is hung on a thread. The lantern only weighs 20 grams, but it pulls the thread taught.

I want to light the lantern with a small LED. Despite the increase in weight from the LED and solder, even 36 gauge wire (enameled copper; regular insulation would look horrid) has nasty kinks and noticeable bumps in it at 1 meter length. This will get worse with the second wire needed to complete the circuit.

What conductive materials (I have considered carbon-based solutions) could be used to get a rigidity somewhere between wire and thread, preferably not so small it could snap? I imagine I will have to add a polyurethane coating myself as insulation if I found the right wire.

Comment: @jsotola there are hundreds of these ;) They will all be dimmed and controlled via one central unit.

Comment: Thinner wire...

Comment: Lamp cord is also made from very fine strands of wire. The overall thickness is much  to thick for what you are doing. But the strand diameter is probably OK.

Comment: Just a random thought. If you use straight, rigid rod would that be acceptable? Maybe thin tempered steel rod. Steel is a lousy conductor, but it sounds like the current is so low that a lousy conductor might be OK.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing @jsotola’s comment (which seems to have been removed?!) about headphone cables, I decided to fish out some old broken Apple headphones I had in a bottom drawer.

The headphone cable with insulation was too bulky and rigid for my application, but inside the insulator were five conductors that looked exactly like thread. Sure enough, Apple and friends have already designed thread-like cables to put inside their headphones. There are fibers woven into the conductors as well to make them even more supple.

I took two of the three insulated strands (red green and blue) and hooked them up to the light. Hangs like a charm, pretty bright too!

Because apple headsets are expensive ;), my next challenge will be getting ahold of a spool of this stuff. This is exactly what I need!

Comment: If this is a solution to your problem, feel free to accept your own answer.

Comment: I often use Mil-Spec M22759 19-26-9 wire from McCaffrey Associates for headphone wire repairs. This is nominally 26 gauge wire but it is built from 19 strands of silver-plated copper, each strand themselves are 38 gauge. I'm not sure where you could get finer than this. But it's what I use. And the strands are extremely tiny -- I need a microscope these days to visualize them well.

Comment: i removed my comment about using earbud cable because you already read the comment ... you also said that you are building hundreds of the lamps and that amount of cable would be very expensive

Answer (score 0):

You can get down to 40AWG (0.08mm) enamelled copper wire.  But that may not be enough of an improvement.

Conductive thread does exist (Google it), but isn't insulated.  It can be nylon or stainless steel cored.